# Jmeter posting a file where the file path is a variable

Tags: jmeter

newbie to jmeter.

i am trying to test the file upload portion of my site

I need to test multiple upload file types.

so for i have working

-- http request sampler to login

-- http request sampler to upload the file using "Send files with the request" (This is where i have the absolute path tothe upload file. where i would like to put a variable)

-- another http sampler to validate the upload

This all works fine. Now i want to loop through different scenarios based on the the thread count

```
int idx = ctx.getThreadNum();
```

I load some values for that loop based on idx

the part i can not get working is uploading a file specific to the thread idx

to hack this to get it working i have Swith controllers for each thread id that uploads a different file. this is problematic as each thread i want to add, i will have to add a new switch controller. This can not be the correct way to do it.

I appreciate any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use [__threadNum()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__threadNum) function in the "File Path" input like:

[image: File Path ThreadNum]

The function returns current thread number (starting with 1) so you will be able to upload different files with different threads.

By the way, `int idx = ctx.getThreadNum();` returns thread numbers starting from 0, maybe that's why your test doesn't work as expected.

[image: Beanshell versus function]

See [How to Use JMeter Functions](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeter-functions-part-iii) articles series for comprehensive information on above and other useful JMeter functions.